# How to select everything within three months of a given date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 columns I am focusing on. One stores a date value and the other stores a timestamp value. How can I select from each column to find data when the date or datetime is within 90 days?

For example, I am looking for something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column in range (current_date + 90);
```

and similarly for the timestamp column

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_with_timezone_column IN RANGE (current_timestamp_with_timezone + 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an interval to suit

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date_column <= current_date + INTERVAL '3 MONTH'
-- or if you prefer 
-- WHERE date_column <= current_date + INTERVAL '90 DAY'
```

much the same for timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE timestamp_with_timezone_column <= current_timestamp + INTERVAL '3 MONTH'
```

or, if wanting to remove current time of day  then perhaps:

```
WHERE timestamp_with_timezone_column <= date_trunc('day',current_timestamp) + INTERVAL '3 MONTH'
```